# Nginx Redirect all except Index

Tags: nginx

We've recently moved different language pages into folders on our site.

Eg.

```
example.com/uk
example.com/de
example.com/ie
```

When a user lands at example.com they are greeted with a page to select their language.

For SEO/bookmark purposes I'd like to redirect all traffic hitting previous pages to the uk version.

Eg

```
example.com/page1.php
```

would redirect to

```
example.com/uk/page1.php
```

But at the same time any that land on example.com root would be shown the language selector.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use `nginx` to read a `cookie` value on requests to the index. If the cookie with a value exists redirect otherwise show the index.

Comment: There are many solutions. It would be helpful to see the main logic in your existing `server` block.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I guess, I can answer for future visitors. My example was this:

We moved our domain to a subdomain after adding a new vertical for our business. It was a NextJS SPA application. The condition was, any request to https://example.com should be routed to https://subdomain.example.com, but at the same time, we had to show a home page at https://example.com. In order to achieve this, because the nginx applies logic in the order we add location blocks, I had to apply logic in following order:

1. Route the index to it's proper location

   ```
       location / {

           root /home/ubuntu/projects/tbs/front-end/home-page/;
           index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   }
   ```
2. Since our structure are like this: https://subdomain.example.com/my-product-name-and-some-random-text, where anything with a hyphen may be a product slug, I had to ensure that before checking for product, we had to redirect any other url to their respective pages. The location blocks were:

   ```
       location /products {
           return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
   }
       location /about {
           return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
   }
       location /contact {
           return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```
3. Finally, we had to add a regex to route anything else with a hyphen with an assumption that it is a product

   ```
   location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$ {
           return 301 https://subdomain.example.com$request_uri;
   }
   ```

   I am sure that there may be a better solution than the one we used, but considering our less experience with nginx, it was a pretty good workaround. If anyone has a better solution, I would love to hear so we can do it in a better way.